# How to create a binomial field in a raster from a polygon overlay?

Tags: r, gis, raster, arcmap

I have a raster where each attribute field represents a different input in a fire risk model. I'm trying to test my model's skill at predicting fire locations. I have polygons representing two years of fire perimeters (years that weren't used to train the original model).

I'd like to create a binomial presence/absence field in my raster based on the fire polygons, where presence represents cells overlaid by a fire polygon and absence represents areas that did not burn in the study period. I'd like to include cells that are both completely and partially overlaid by a fire polygon as presences. Is there a good way to do this in either ArcMap or R?

I've considered rasterizing my polygons but that seems clunky. I'd like to avoid losing resolution if at all possible.

Comment: I think there are a few packages such as Rgeos, raster and maybe sf that have intersect functions that work on rasters and polygons. Maybe this post is of interest to you :https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/276928/raster-intersect-and-gintersection-give-different-results-in-r

Answer (score 0):

You say two contradictory things. First

> I'd like to create a presence/absence raster based on the fire
> polygons

And then

> I've considered rasterizing my polygons but that seems clunky

Based on your goal (first statement) you could start with

```
r <- rasterize(x, y, field=1, getCover=TRUE)
```

(in the terra or raster packages)

Comment: To clarify, I have two separate objects. 1) A raster of fire risk indices 2) polygons of actual fire boundaries. I think I misspoke in my original explanation- I'd like to create a binomial field in the existing raster based off whether or not its overlaid by a fire polygon, not a new raster. I'm hesitant to rasterize because I don't want to lose resolution of my fire polygons.

Comment: I do not understand the distinction you make between "rasterization" and "creating a new field" (and the latter is not common raster-speak). There are ways to address difference in resolution (getCover, disaggregate, .....) Can edit your question and include a reproducible example. See, e.g. ?raster::rasterize for ideas how to set this up; and telling us what you expect as output?.